# How to scale authorization for my resource management system

Tags: postgresql, architecture, authorization

I have two systems

One Access management system where I store references of resources, users and access rights between them.

One Resource management system where I keep data about the resources and provide and an API to manage and query them.

When a request is received in the Resource management system, a query is sent to the Access management system to get a list of resource ids, to which the current user have access. This list is used as a criteria in the Resource Management PostgreSQL database when fetching data from it, so I only return results for data the user has access to.

This works fine in the small scale when a user have access up to a couple of hundred resources, but how do I scale this to work for users with access to 2000 or 20000 resources? I can't pass 20000 resource ids between my systems for every request!

Answer (score 1):

Your design seems to be the problem.

It is odd to separate objects and their access control in different systems. Apart from the inefficiencies you are experiencing, it will be difficult to keep the systems synchonized.

One proven method (that PostgreSQL uses) is to store the permissions on the objects themselves as an "access control list". Then you know if somebody may access an object or not without fetching additional data. Another advantage is that permissions are automatically removed with the object.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly create a temporary table for the resource ids and make a join with the more permanent data in the db. It might be worth a try to see if it fits your use case.